# equals not working with same value with different datatype

Tags: java

I have two objects as below:

```
Object obj1 = new BigDecimal(123);
Object obj2 = new Long(123);

if(obj1.equals(obj2))
 System.out.println("both are equal");
else
 System.out.println("both are not equal");
```

it is showing that both are not equal. Is it comparing based on datatype?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it comparing based on datatype?

Yes, exactly as it's documented to. From [`BigDecimal.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> **Returns** true if and only if the specified Object is a `BigDecimal` whose value and scale are equal to this `BigDecimal`'s.

And from [`Long.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a `Long` object that contains the same `long` value as this object.

It's very rarely a good idea for objects of different types to compare equal to each other - typically in an `equals` implementation you'll have something like:

```
if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

Or if your class is `final`, you can just use:

```
if (!(other instanceof MyClass)) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course your `Object`s are not equal.

The `equals` overrides for `BigDecimal` and `Long` check that the reference type is respectively `BigDecimal` and `Long` as an early check.

In `BigDecimal`:

```
if (!(obj instanceof BigDecimal))
         return false; // not a decimal
```

In `Long`:

```
if (obj instanceof Long) {
    return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
}
return false;
```

You can improve your code as follows:

```
Number obj1 = new BigDecimal(123);
Number obj2 = new Long(123);
if (obj1.longValue() == obj2.longValue()) {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is showing that both are not equal. Is it comparing based on datatype?

Yes, if you check out `BigDecimal`'s equals() implementation you would see the following

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    if (!(x instanceof BigDecimal))
        return false;
```

That's a **standard** practice to return `false` if the objects being compared are not of the same *type*. The same is reflected in the Java docs for [BigDecimal#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is checking for the second argument to be of `BigDecimal`.

Code  in `BigDecimal` class :

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
        if (!(x instanceof BigDecimal)) // gets Long here. SO returns false
            return false;
       .....
}
```

**Note** : 2 *different* types with *same* value are *different*

Answer (score 0):

Because they're actually not the same!

You have to understand better what "equal method" is supposed to do.

You're not comparing numbers, you're comparing objects, and the answer you got fulfills the method's contract